# Check all TextViews in an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I was wondering if it is possible to run a check against all the TextViews in an Activity/View and make ones which don't have any content in them invisible? I don't really want to wrap a if statement around each of the TextViews when setting text.

I currently have an activity that will populate a range of TextViews with content from a Database. However there is a chance that some fields in the database will not have any content and to keep a clean UI I want to simply make these fields invisible instead of them just sitting blank.

Here is where I am setting the content:

```
public void settingContent() {

    eventTitle.setText(event.EventTitle);
    eventLocation.setText(event.SiteName);
    organiser.setText(event.Organiser);
    eventType.setText(event.setEventTitle());

    DateFormatter dateFormatter = new DateFormatter();

    String startDate = dateFormatter.getFormattedDate(event.StartDateTime);
    String endDate = dateFormatter.getFormattedDate(event.CloseDateTime);
    String eventDates = startDate + " - " + endDate;
    dates.setText(eventDates);

    cost.setText(event.FeeDetails);
    bookingContact.setText(event.BookingContactName);
    stewardContact.setText(event.StewardContactName);
    unitTypes.setText(event.MaxUnits);
    mapReference.setText(event.MapReference);
    eventNumber.setText(event.EventNumber);
    otherInformation.setText(event.OtherInformation);
    directions.setText(event.SiteRouting);

    if(event.isTempHoliday()) {
        eventIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_holidaysites_card);
    } else {
        eventIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_clubmeets_card);
    }
}
```

So is this possible or is it a case of just having to check each individual TextView before setting?

Comment: Maybe create a custome textview (extend Textview) and just add a line to make it hide by default.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The TextView is set by you. Why would you test if it has text? If it has text, you put it there.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<TextView> lstTexts = new ArrayList<TextView>();
lstTexts.add(cost);
lstTexts.add(bookingContact);
lstTexts.add(stewardContact);
lstTexts.add(unitTypes);
lstTexts.add(mapReference);
lstTexts.add(eventNumber);
lstTexts.add(otherInformation);
lstTexts.add(directions);

//then you can run this method
boolean empty = checkAllTV(lstTexts);
```

This is the method for it.

```
public boolean checkAllTV(List<TextView> allTV){

     for(TextView tv : allTV){
         if(tv.getText().toString().equals("")||tv.getText().toString()==null)
               return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

I am on Mobile so I am not able to check the code! but you can get the idea.
Hope it Helps.